CMAKE error . CMake Error: The source directory does not exist
I have spent hours trying to solve this, finally asking for help!
Here is the CMAKE:
dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build/opencv-4.8.1/build$ cmake -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \ 
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib-4.8.1/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
    -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
    -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
    -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON \
    -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENMP=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D BUILD_TBB=ON \
    -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=TRUE \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
    -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages ..

CMake Error: The source directory "/home/dk/opencv_build/opencv-4.8.1/build/ " does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
-D: command not found

Here are my steps:
dk@ASUS:~$ mkdir ~/opencv_build && cd ~/opencv_build
dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build$ 

dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build$ mkdir -p ~/opencv_build/opencv-4.8.1/build 
dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build$ l
total 151M
drwxrwxr-x  4 dk dk 4.0K Apr 24 20:24 .
drwxr-x--- 17 dk dk 4.0K Apr 24 20:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x 12 dk dk 4.0K Apr 24 20:26 opencv-4.8.1
drwxrwxr-x  6 dk dk 4.0K Jun 28  2023 opencv_contrib-4.8.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  59M Apr 24 20:24 opencv_contrib.zip
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  93M Apr 24 20:23 opencv.zip
dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build$ cd opencv-4.8.1
dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build/opencv-4.8.1$ l
total 156K
drwxrwxr-x 12 dk dk 4.0K Apr 24 20:26 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 dk dk 4.0K Apr 24 20:24 ..
drwxrwxr-x 25 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 3rdparty
drwxrwxr-x 10 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 apps
drwxrwxr-x  2 dk dk 4.0K Apr 24 20:26 build
drwxrwxr-x  9 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 cmake
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  73K Sep 27  2023 CMakeLists.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  191 Sep 27  2023 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  733 Sep 27  2023 COPYRIGHT
drwxrwxr-x  7 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 data
drwxrwxr-x  8 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 doc
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  455 Sep 27  2023 .editorconfig
drwxrwxr-x  3 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 include
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  12K Sep 27  2023 LICENSE
drwxrwxr-x 23 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 modules
drwxrwxr-x 14 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 platforms
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk  844 Sep 27  2023 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 24 dk dk 4.0K Sep 27  2023 samples
-rw-rw-r--  1 dk dk 3.1K Sep 27  2023 SECURITY.md
dk@ASUS:~/opencv_build/opencv-4.8.1$ cd build


When I'm in this build directory, I run the cmake command... as shown above... and I get the error.  Clearly however, my opencv SOURCE folder is there... but not in the build sub-directory.
What I am doing wrong?

"learly however, my opencv SOURCE folder is there" - Your OpenCV source directory is ~/opencv_build/opencv-4.8.1. For cmake the source directory is specified by using non-keyword parameter. If you have found that command line in some manual, then you probably forgot the last .. parameter.

This issue is solved.  There was an error is my bash script.
